# Detecting unset variables in Django templates

Tags: django, templates, variables

As a long time PHP developer, I'm used to the idea of setting the error level for my application to warn me when I am using an uninitialized variable.  I was wondering if a similar feature exists in Django, where I can detect at run-time that I am using a variable in my template that was not explicitly passed to the template via the view?

For example, I misspelled a variable name in the template

```
{{ mysearch }}
```

When it should've been

```
{{ my_search }}
```

Common mistake, not paying attention while typing, etc.  In PHP I would've seen a warning about using an uninitiailzed variable but Django doesn't seem to care and just keeps on going like nothing happened.  From a debugging perspective, it would be awesome to detect when I've made a mistake like that.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for this?  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/api/#invalid-template-variables

Have you tried setting `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID`?  e.g.,

```
TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID = 'DEBUG WARNING: template variable [%s] is not defined'
```

That will cause that string to be printed in the rendered html for each spot where an undefined variable was referenced, along with the variable name.

Read this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/settings/#setting-TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID

Comment: My problem was I did not know *how* to frame the question is such a way  that Google could find me an answer.  Thanks so much!

Comment: I didn't use Google.  I flipped through the pages of the template documentation on the Django site.

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of Django you can get [messages about unset template variables by outputting messages from the 'django.template' logger](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/logging/#django-template) by modifying the `LOGGING` setting.

```py
LOGGING = {
    # ... [SNIP]
    'loggers': {
        # ... [SNIP]
        'django.template': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        }
    },
}
```